# Fully differential amplifier - adder?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, differential, active-filter, differential-amplifier

I have two signal sources providing the *same* differential audio signal (**VIN1** and **VIN2**). I want to sum those signals. The result (**VOUT**) shall also be differential.

The idea is to take a fully-differential op-amp and to sum the inputs just as you would do it in a single ended inverting adder configuration.

Will this work?

A quick LTspice simulation seems to work as expected. However, I could not find any examples on the internet, so maybe I am missing something?

[image: Fully differential adder]

Answer (score 2):

That works - both device inputs are virtual earths so the currents from the signal sources sum at these points and you make a fully differential adder.